# Commas, series off adjectives

Tags: commas

In American English would you put a comma after both adjectives or, as in British you put it only after the first.

The big, red, dog...
Or
The big, red dog...
?

Comment: Hello, aJ. It's difficult to respond to a claim that's off-target. I'm not sure about any minor differences between US and UK punctuation, but no competent Anglophone would put a comma between _big_ and _red_ here except in very rare circumstances for marking. And I can't see any circumstance where there'd be a comma before _dog_. Look at the duplicate to find out about when commas between adjectives are needed or are used to differentiate meanings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need to use a comma between two adjectives?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/344091/do-i-need-to-use-a-comma-between-two-adjectives). See also [Are these two adjectives acting as coordinate adjectives or cumulative adjectives?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/442413/are-these-two-adjectives-acting-as-coordinate-adjectives-or-cumulative-adjective).

Comment: Even in British grammar, you *could* use a comma before dog—so long as *red* was being used as a piece of nonessential information. However, it would not be normal, and different punctuation would convey that particular meaning much better: *The big (and red) dog . . .* Otherwise, it would *look* like a mistake, even if used deliberately.

Answer (score 1):

Although I speak British English, I can safely say that the two are the same in this respect. You would never need to put a comma between a final adjective and a noun.

These rules might help you a little more:

https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/607/02/

Rule 6 directly relates to your question here.

Comment: Hello, joseph. This question should be close-voted rather than answered, for several reasons.